# Debian Stretch - The repository 'http://192.168.196.1/sw/repo/deb9 stretch Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: debian, apt-get, stretch

I have downloaded Debian Stretch Repo using apt-mirror and hosted it locally.

When I am doing an apt-get update, I am getting the following warning:

```
W: The repository 'http://192.168.196.1/sw/repo/deb9 stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Please note that I am able to install packages.

However, I would like to know how can I remove this warning.

Answer (score 1):

Change the /etc/apt/sources.list from

```
deb http://192.168.196.1/sw/repo/deb9/ stretch main
```

to

```
deb [trusted=1] http://192.168.196.1/sw/repo/deb9/ stretch main
```